# TableView, Array and segue

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I am a beginner in swift this actually my second week . I try to teach my self by building simple code.

I build a table using class and array,

```
    var cell = [Cell]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cell = [
            Cell(Title:"cell1", number: 5),
            Cell(Title:"cell2",  number: 3),
            Cell(Title:"cell3", number: 4),
]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
           }
```

If I click one of the cells I will move to next controller. Here the idea, all the cell will take me to the same  controller the only difference is the number of the cells so I want to pass the data

cell[row].number

to next controller

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "next" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
           let selectedcell = cell[indexPath.row]
            let dest = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

            dest.cells = selectedcell


        }}
```

My problem is I wasnt able to use cells in DetailViewController maybe their is  code for pass the data of array or something. I want to use cells.number as the  number of cells when I build the table. I know there simple way by making each cells points to different Controller but if I have big data it will take forever.

thank you

Comment: what's the data type of dest.cells? is it an array of Cell? if it is, you can't assign Cell instance to an array of Cells

Comment: what is the problem you are exactly experiencing?

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with

```
dest.cells = selectedcell
```

You are trying to pass 1 Cell object to a variable containing (i suppose, from the plural) an array of Cell-s.

- If you just want to pass 1 cell just correct the destination type to `Cell`.
- If you want to pass an array of cells then you need to tell us with which policy
- If you want to instantiate in the destination view controller as many new cells as the number defined by the selected `cell.number` then pass the cell as you are doing and in the destination view controller implement the needed uitableviewdelegate/datasource and instantiate them.

*[Should be a comment but is too long]*